# Thermal shutdown feature in an IC

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, thermal, ldo, linear-regulator

I'd like to understand more about thermal shutdown in an IC.

I have read that, if the IC junction temperature exceeds beyond a certain limit, the IC shuts down itself which is known as thermal shutdown.

How does it recover and start to work normally once the IC is shutdown?

1. Do we need to do a power cycle to make the IC work?
2. Will the IC start working again once the junction temp reduces to a certain value?

How does it go back work?

I'm using [this IC](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic5353.pdf). Not much information is given regarding the IC's thermal shutdown. It is only mentioned that this IC has this feature.

What conditions should happen for this IC (also in general) to go into thermal shutdown?

Answer (score 2):

Normally this information would be found by referring to this section of the data sheet on page 8: -

[image]

However, the hyper-link doesn't work so I found the book [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/ldobk.pdf): -

[image]

It's worth reading to see what it says because it's likely to contain the answer to your question. If you want an opinion, it will shut-down on over-temperature and naturally re-start proper operation at a lower temperature thus providing hysteresis. Of course, it may shutdown in a way that keeps the junction from exceeding the temperature limit by just lowering the output voltage.

Maybe this section is worth reading: -

[image]

It's on page 61 and says: -

> Die temperature is monitored, and if it becomes excessive, the thermal
> shutdown circuit activates, clamping the base of Q2 and shutting down
> Q1. The flag circuit looks at the output voltage sample and compares
> it to a reference set 5% lower. If the sample is even lower, the flag
> comparator saturates the open collector flag transistor, signaling the
> fault condition.

So, this looks like a partial explanation.

Comment: Oh Ok. So, power cycle of the device is not required to make it start working again right? Like, if the temp increases, cause shutdown, and temperature decreases, the device will start working again, right?

Comment: You need to read the book I linked. I'm scanning through it but, if it's not 100% clear then you should contact Micrel @Newbie

Comment: Thank you @Andy. But in general for any device having the thermal shutdown feature, how does it come back after thermal shutdown?

Comment: @Newbie In general, it comes back however it's been designed to. Customers don't like things that need to be cycled, so you'll probably find most things will reset themselves. For any given device though, read the datasheet for that device. If it's still not clear after that, contact the manufacturer.

Comment: @Newbie There is no general answer for this. Any particular device may do one of several things and, different manufacturer's may favour one method over another. It may linearly reduce output drive current to keep the die at a stable temperature (thus protecting it) or, it may go into forced shut-down and wait for the temperature to lower by (say) 20 deg before restarting or, it may do something else. If the book I linked doesn't give you the specific answer you need, you should contact Micrel.

Comment: @Newbie If you use it like that, it won't last long. Think of it more like a fuse to prevent fire when something goes wrong than something you intentionally design for it to regularly use. Do not use thermal shut down as a power limiter.